# How to use a Angular CurrencyPipe on a Material column?

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to use a Angular CurrencyPipe on a Material column. All my columns are dynamic and present in `tableView.columns`

My template is

```html
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of tableView.columns;let i=index">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{col}}</mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell [class]="tRow.cells[i].classes" *matCellDef="let tRow">{{ tRow.cells[i].text }}</mat-cell>
  <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ tableView.footer.cells[i].text }}</mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
```

In my last column I want add `| currency`

Comment: `{{ tRow.cells[i].text | currency }}` no?

Comment: I do not want currency pipe on all cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I didn't read you wanted the last column to be piped.

You can use the last variable on your `ngFor`. To see if it's the last column.

```html
<ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of tableView.columns;let i=index; let last=last;">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{col}}</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell [class]="tRow.cells[i].classes" *matCellDef="let tRow">
      <span *ngIf="last">
        {{ tRow.cells[i].text | currency}}
      </span>
      <span *ngIf="!last">
          {{ tRow.cells[i].text}}
        </span>
    </mat-cell>
    <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ tableView.footer.cells[i].text }}</mat-footer-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     <ng-container [matColumnDef]="col" *ngFor="let col of tableView.columns;let i=index;let last=last">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{col}}</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell  [class]="tRow.cells[i].classes" *matCellDef="let tRow">
             <span *ngIf="!last">{{ tRow.cells[i].text }}</span>
             <span *ngIf="last">{{ tRow.cells[i].text |currency}}</span>
            </mat-cell>       
            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef>{{ tableView.footer.cells[i].text}}</mat-footer-cell>      
     </ng-container>
```

Comment: I do not want currency pipe on all footer cells (juste last column)